# Ignore files in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tfvc, azure-devops

I want to ignore some files from an `ASP.NET` Core project I am using with `VSTS` and `TFVC`.

I made some research and people say that a `.tfignore` file should be enough, but it doesn't prevent the folder i don't want to be present in the Included Changes.

I tried a `.tfignore` with this.

```
\wwwroot\lib
```

And it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: Are you trying to have the folders marked as "excluded" when you do an Add operation on the root folder within Visual Studio so they aren't added to the Pending Changes?

Comment: Are you using a server workspace or a local workspace?

Comment: Yes @Taegost I don't want that folder to be included in Pending Changes. And Daniel Mann I'm using local workspace I think, since I mapped the server's in my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.tfignore does not work with Asp.Net5 (Named as Asp.Net Core1.0 now) project. This is a known issue. Refer to this link for details: [Things in ".tfignore" still are shown in the Solution Explorer (and in pending changes)](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification